# What should the next value?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column which is Number datatype and Nullable. Right now there is no record available. And the column value is generated using the next_val.

Will the first value of the column be able to generate a number, or i do have to assign the first number manually.

Please let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

Create a **sequence**, and use **sequence.nextval** to use the sequence number.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE s START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

Sequence created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(A NUMBER);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t SELECT s.nextval FROM dual;

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

         A
----------
         1

SQL>
```

I have written a small article on **trigger-sequence** approach to populate the sequence in prior 12c releases. See http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/auto-increment-primary-key-in-pre-12c-releases-identity-functionality/

If you are on 12c, you could use the **IDENTITY column**. Read http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/identity-column-autoincrement-functionality-in-oracle-12c/